# Xamarin.Ui.Test Inject_Events permission

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do app.Back() when a share selection dialog is displayed. The error is:

> System.Exception : Error while performing Back()
>
> System.Exception : PressKey for keycode:'KEYCODE_BACK' was unsucessful: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

How can I add permissions to the project?

Comment: You mean when you open an external application, and  unable to get back to your application again?

Comment: Yes, when I press a button the typical dialog to share appears. To close it i need to press back button but the program detects that is not on my app and can't do it. i understand that the problem can be solved with INJECT_EVENTS permission but didn't work.

Comment: And pretty exactly one year later: i have the same error. Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this permission if you right click in your Android project, then you go to Android manifest tab and finally you mark that permission in the bottom list.

Comment: I added the permission in the manifest but I get the same error. The project is developed in xamarin.

Comment: I think the permission isn't needed for the android project, but for the test project itself...